# Why aren't Visualforce errors showing up in the Developer Console?

Tags: visualforce, developer-console

I'm fairly sure Visualforce error messages used to appear in the Developer Console (prior to Winter '14), but they're not showing up for me.

The Log Levels are all set to `FINEST`.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Is there something that I missed or some setting that's not turned on?

Comment: Try turning on Development Mode and see if that helps. Not having Developer Mode on sometimes causes odd behavior with logging.

Comment: Even with Development Mode turned on, the error doesn't appear in the log in the Developer Console.

Comment: I was able to reproduce many times same issue .Something wrong after winter 14 release .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Winter 14 bug.  It is not yet listed in the known issues.  I logged a case with SF 5 days ago.  It has been escalated twice already and they are still trying to find the root cause of the issue.  They still tell me 'They can't isolate the issue and are still trying to resolve'.  They do however admit that is a Winter 14 bug.

I know that's not the answer you are looking for but thought I would let you know that you're not the only person getting this issue, and SF is aware of it, but the more people that log cases for this the more light will be shed on the issue, so please log cases with support for this issue

Comment: Strangely I have the same issue in my Summer '13 Developer Org. This may be a new issue, but it isn't just affected by Winter '14. I'm fairly certain that I did see Visualforce Errors in the Developer Console before, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That is very odd, I'm pretty certain I saw VF errors in the console before and this just started for me with the Winter 14 release.  Have you heard back from SF yet on your case?

Comment: I did, and they told me the same. Only Apex errors are logged. If VF errors were indeed never logged, I think I'll create an Idea to log them (seems to be common sense).

Comment: They are now telling me the same thing, despite telling me it was due to Winter 14 earlier, but I'm like 99% positive that they showed VF errors as well.

Comment: Here's a link to the idea I created: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kv6TAAQ.

Comment: An update on this issue: not all Apex Errors are appearing in the Debug Logs, either... I just received a "Content cannot be displayed: Attempt to de-reference a null object" error that isn't appearing in the logs.